CPUs with lower IDs are used more often
I have intel i9-13900k it is 8 regular core with threading and additional 16 efficiency cores.
I am running  with kernel 6.9 on ArchLinux
I have noticed the CPUs with the lower ID’s have high percent usage compare for the higher ID’s, In particular CPU0 is used the most.
Can this CPU scheduling cause a higher rate of failure to the lower cores and thus more frequent failure of the entire cpu. This is because the heat is mostly concentrated in the lower CPUs and it does not spread evenly.
If that is the case, is there a way to mitigate it so that I can prolong the life of the CPU?

No, that’s the best way to answer your question. Your theory of the heatmap isn’t accurate

Do the cores reach anywhere near the temperature stated as the maximum in specs, or are they just higher relatively speaking?

No CPU is overheating. My question is simple. When making core 0 the main workhorse of the entire CPU and thus unevenly distributing the heat. Can this decrease the lifetime of the entire CPU. This is a type of issue that I cannot test on a single computer because of statistical variability.

Though I doubt that it would affect the useful lifetime of the CPU, you can experiment in Arch Linux with the Kernel I/O Scheduler. "The Multi-Queue Block I/O Queuing Mechanism (blk-mq) maps I/O queries to multiple queues, the tasks are distributed across threads and therefore CPU cores."
Directions are given for viewing scheduling options and for changing them. Then it would up to you to check core temperatures and execution speed, and see if there is an improvement on your system.
If you do so, please come back to provide a more specific answer to your question than this one.
